# Can't get outer html of WebView in HTML when site is on cookiebot

Tags: c#, uwp, geocaching, cookiebot

when I load my web, it returns html corretly.

But when I load any page of geocaching.com, I get source like that (you must be logined, otherwise it give other but still wrong content):

```
`https://pastebin.com/QJLS1Py3`
```

I'm logined and accepted all cookies (visible on https://www.geocaching.com/account/documents/cookies).

When anyone will have solution which use HttpRequest / WebClient it's also appreciate, when it will be returning content like user is logined (many of data is hidden when user is not logined).

How can I get outer html of page?

Video of behaviours: https://vimeo.com/391693855

Thanks for help!

Comment: I have created sample solution to demonstrate behavior: https://github.com/PatrikHorka/GeoCachingComGetSource

Comment: I tested your project and when first loaded the webView, it asked me to login. Then I logged in successfully and accepted cookies. After that, I closed the project and launched again. This time, when the webView  was loaded, I directly went to the search page and returned the outerHTML. Do you mean you can't get outer html after you login? Can you show more details about the unexpected behavior?

Comment: Hi Faywang. Can you post your source code or video what you did?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried on three Windows instalation, Windows 10 stable, Windows 10 Insider and Windows Server 2016 R2. On every with SDK 10.0.18362.1 and 10.0.17763.0. On every of Windows with two geocaching account, on every with same wrong result. I was thinking whether is responsible for it IP address but I didn't find any good USA VPN and VPS is joined with Czech IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solveeeed! I have to do it several second delayed. Was enough insert something like in before eval.

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```